# XML Liquid Studio 2018 - Schema Subset - similar to XmlSpy

Tags: xsd, schema, subset, liquid-xml

I am using the evaluation version at the moment and it compares very well with the features I need from XmlSpy.

I have a rather large Schema file (XSD) and from time to time I like to extract small, self contained, single file, xsd portions from it. Just like XMLSpy (Schema Subset ...).

You have an option to flatten Schema's but I cannot see an option to extract a subset.

Is there such an option?

Many thanks,
Toy

Comment: Not currently but it sounds a useful tool and easy to implement, so I have added it to the suggested features list for consideration. Hopefully this will then be included in the next point release.

Comment: Excellent, As it's easy to implement, do you have an estimated time frame on the next point release (assuming it goes in)?